# Sorting by nested Dictionary value?

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
var userInformation = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

I need a new dictionary that equals this one, but is sorted first by key then by the value's value. I tried:

```
var resultInformation = userInformation.OrderBy(k => k.Key).ThenBy(v => v.Value.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value));
```

I tried a couple of other methods but no effect.

Comment: Dictionaries aren't sorted (in the traditional sense).

Comment: Yes, my bad. I need to order them. Just my natural way of expression.

Comment: You want to sort by which value in the value?

Comment: First I want to Order resultInformation by userInformation's keys and then by userInformation's nested dictionary value's values. That would be the integer values of the nested dictionary, not the keys. They represent a grade which varies from 0 to 100. The key of the dictionary itself is username of the student that applies the score. the string in the nested represents the course in which they apply the score and the integer is their score. I need to print on a console first the names order in alphabetical order and then for each user his scores in different courses ordered by descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries aren't sorted, but you can easily produce a list/collection of the items in your dictionaries, like so:

```
var resultInformation = from outer in userInformation
                        from inner in outer.Value
                        let data = new { Outer = outer.Key, Inner = inner.Key, Value = inner.Value }
                        orderby data.Outer, data.Inner, data.Value
                        select data;
```

Or the query syntax equivalent:

```
var resultInformation = userInformation
    .SelectMany(i => i.Value, (key, inner) => new { Outer = key, Inner = inner.Key, Value = inner.Value})
    .OrderBy(e => e.Outer)
    .ThenBy(e => e.Inner)
    .ThenBy(e => e.Value);
```

**Update**: Based on your clarifying comment, I think what you really want is something more like this:

```
var resultInformation = 
    from student in userInformation
    orderby student.Key
    select new
    {
        studentId = student.Key,
        courses = 
            from courseScore in student.Value
            orderby courseScore.Value descending
            select new {
                course = courseScore.Key,
                score = courseScore.Value
            }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I believe the third option would serve me great, only if I knew how to print it on the Console Application, ha ha. I am quite new to programming and have yet to study such things as the ones you posted. I kind of get all three of them but with my level of knowledge I could hardly implement them. I have made an exact copy of your third option, but do not know how to print it. There can be multiple students of course and multiple scores and courses.

Comment: After a little bit of research I realized it was so simple to print them again with a foreach loop. And it works perfectly fine!  Thank you very much for the answer :)